# Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Error when opening Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I open a solution in VS 2015 Enterprise, I get a message dialog telling me that there has been an error, possibly caused  by an exception and to check the `activitylog.xml` file for more info. I've checked the file, and it seems to be an intellisense error rather than a plugin. Any ides on how to fix?

```
 <entry>
<record>531</record>
<time>2016/12/07 01:18:33.934</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
<description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass22_0.&lt;CreateIndicator&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensDataPointTemplateService.CreateIndicator(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor, String dataPointProviderName, Func`1 viewModelReferenceFactory)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.CreateIndicator(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor, Lazy`2 provider)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection.UpdateTemplateCollection()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection.Connect()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.IndicatorCollection..ctor(CodeLensIndicatorService indicatorService, ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensIndicatorService.CreateIndicatorCollection(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentViewModelProvider.CreateAdornmentViewModel(ICodeLensDescriptor descriptor)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentCache.GetOrCreateCacheEntry(ICodeLensTag tag)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensAdornmentCache.GetOrCreateAdornment(ICodeLensTag tag)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTagger.AdornmentHost.TryConnectAdornment()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.Implementation.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTaggerProvider.CodeLensInterLineAdornmentTagger.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass41_0.&lt;CreateDelayedAdornments&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint[T](Object errorSource, Func`1 call, T valueOnThrow)</description>
```

Comment: happens for every solution or particular one?

Comment: happens for all solutions

Comment: Does this happen for any solution? or only for one particular solution?  If it happens for all solutions try doing a repair installation.  If it is for only 1 single solution, try deleting the .suo file from your solution directory.

Comment: even for newly created ones?

Comment: Yes. Complete re-install was needed to fix the problem